# Como faço para comparar matrizes de diferentes tamanhos no Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Eu tenho duas matrizes com valores numericos: A (tamanho 44x1) e B (tamanho 42x1).

O que eu preciso fazer é:

- contar quantas vezes os valores aparecem repetidos para A e B.
- saber se estes valores que se repetem são comuns nas duas matrizes, se sim, dividir suas contagens.

Exemplo: 0.5 aparece 600 vzs na matriz A e 300 vzs na matriz B, então divide 600 por 300.
0.7 aparece 200 vzs na matriz A e 100 vzs na matriz B, então divide 200 por 100.

No final eu preciso ter duas colunas: uma com os numeros repetidos e outra com os valores da divisão.

```
| 0.5 | 2 | 
|:---- |:------:|
| 0.7 | 2   |
```

Em python fica assim:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/data1.xlsx')

data2 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/data2.xlsx')

for i in data1['Mag'].value_counts() & data2['Mag'].value_counts():

  a = data1['Mag'].value_counts()/data2['Mag'].value_counts()

  print(a)

  break
```

Como faço em matlab? Valeu!